# Simple telnet example in LIBCURL - C++

Tags: c++, curl, telnet, libcurl

I need to fing simple TELNET example in LIBCURL (curl.haxx.se/libcurl) (C++)
I searched over this site, but I don't found any simple example.
I need only to connect to TELNET, authenticate, and send message.

Thanks

Comment: Hey, there are a lot of examples, but they are hidden :D
http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/fileupload.html is one of them. In the right there is list with all examples.

Answer (score 1):

All you can do in libcurl is send data and recieve data. There is no way to wait for response or send data based on response. The whole point of libcurl is to handle waiting for data and responses for HTTP or FTP.

That being said, you may be able to do something with `CURLOPT_READFUNCTION` and `CURL_READFUNC_PAUSE`. Return `PAUSE` from `READFUNCTION`, then call `curl_easy_pause(CURLPAUSE_CONT)` when you see "login:" in your `READFUNCTION`. Be prepared to return your user name from `READFUNCTION` when it gets called.

I've never done this, so I can't vouch for how it works. But from API description, this seems to be the way to go...

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: The telnet protocol does not specify any way to login with a specified user and password so curl can't do that automatically. To do that, you need to track when the login prompt is received and send the username and password accordingly.

You can look it here: http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/documentation/curl/index.html

Maybe you should make it manually like:

```
system("curl telnet://192.168.2.1");
```

Later it will ask your username and password.

Comment: how do you pass the username and password then if you use the system command?