# Communicating over telnet

Tags: c++, visual-studio, libcurl

I can't use [Boost ASIO](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial.html) (reasons not related to programming) and I [looked around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687369/simple-telnet-example-in-libcurl-c) and [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html) looks good. I'm building the binaries at the moment and decided to get some feedback from the community.

Any comments regarding libcurl/alternatives?

#### UPDATE:

libcurl's not great for telnet. It's 2010! Shouldn't there be a simple way to do this? Winsock?

Comment: Yeah, it's 2010 and hardly anyone uses telnet anymore.  Have you considered switching to ssh?  There's a decent library for that at http://www.libssh.org/

Comment: @Zack: Don't have a choice! I can only communicate with the device (robot) over telnet.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? If you can better define the end product (which would explain why you need telnet) it will be easier to help.

Comment: Oh. Hm. Are you sure it's actually *telnet* (as defined by http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc854.html) and not "open a TCP socket to port X, then send and receive byte streams"? I'd expect the latter, and the latter is only a small amount of code on top of the basic socket API.

Comment: @Marm0t: I need to connect to a server via telnet and send commands and receive data from it.

Comment: @Zack: It's Telnet. Mere data isn't being sent around --- the documentation specifically mentions telnet data and the interface upon logging in looks like it's been designed for telnet.

Comment: 10 years ago I was in a similar position... I just used a TCP socket and engaged in just enough TELNET specific interaction re pseudo-terminal type or whatever it was it wanted to be able to start issuing commands.  It is not hard if you pursue it.  Otherwise, you could actually use the telnet binary and control it via expect (a tcl-based utility).

Comment: Why can't you use Boost.Asio? It really sounds like the best tool here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Telnet is a *very* simple protocol.  Some wonky stuff to negotiate the terminal type but I'm sure your robot doesn't care where the cursor ends up.  Just use a socket to open a TCP/IP connection on port 23 and send the command strings, terminated with a '\n'.

Answer (score 1):

RFC854 is referring to it as a protocol, so perhaps it is one.

When I think of telnet I think of connecting to port 23 on a VT100 to get a terminal window to a remote UNIX host. You can also use telnet to other ports to get a TCP/IP connection which we used to use years ago on MUD/Talker servers, but this is simply a regular TCP/IP connection that is used in a connection-based client-server application. Actually "connectionless" is a misnomer as you do connect to the remote server, just in the connectionless model you do not retain the connection throughout the session, whereas in a connection-based model, the session begins when the client connects and ends when it disconnects.

Comment: When was telnet called a protocol?